# Ломает приложение при импорте Electron-а в компонент

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Я делаю приложение на Electron + Vue, у меня такая структура проекта:
В корне проекта файл main.js где сам Electron, и 2 папки, frontend и backend. Внутри frontend сами компоненты, как обычное приложение на Vue.

Но при попытке добавить импорт в компонент vue: `const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');` у меня ломается приложение с ошибкой:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/zacknebeystoll/Desktop/Projects/dev-phone-lab/node_modules/electron'
```

Смотрел решения в интернете, там советовали в package.json/webpack.config.js добавить код на отключение fs, но не помогает.

Кто знает в чём проблема, подскажите, ибо не могу продолжить проект из-за этой ошибки.